# Redirect trafic from exampleapp.herokuapp.com to exampleapp.com Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, http-redirect

I have an Rails 3.2 app hosted on heroku which is currently accessible from many different urls.

https://some-string.herokussl.com

http://myapp.herokuapp.com

https://myapp.herokuapp.com

https://myapp.com

http://myapp.com

I have done www to naked redirect and forced ssl in rails. But it's still accessible from following urls

https://some-string.herokussl.com

https://myapp.herokuapp.com

From SEO perspective it's very wrong.

So, what should I do to redirect traffic from heroku domains to my custom 
domain. Is there some gem or configuration which I should apply in my app.

Thanks!

Comment: @mdesantis I'm using dnsimple so subdomain to apex rediect is no issue here. That's working fine. I just want to redirect from heroku domains.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following to your `application_controller.rb`

```
PREFERED_HOST = 'www.our_domain.tld'
before_filter :redirect_to_prefered_host

...

private
def redirect_to_prefered_host
  if Rails.env.production? && request.host != PREFERED_HOST
    redirect_to(:host => PREFERED_HOST)
  end
end
```

Comment: It works, but redirects http version http://myapp.herokuapp.com to secure https://myapp.herokuapp.com first which then redirects to https://myapp.com/posts. That's default controller path. That's multiple redirects.

Comment: If you have multiple redirect than you combine them into one method. Furthermore I would not care too much about the SEO aspect of this. Naked and SSL should be redirected. But if you do not tell someone the herokuapp.com URLs, no search engine will find that URLs.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [rack-canonical-host](https://github.com/tylerhunt/rack-canonical-host) or [rack-rewrite](https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite)

Comment: I tried rack-canonical-host and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: But my development env redirects http://localhost:3000 to https://myapp.com:3000 even when I'm using 
use Rack::CanonicalHost, ENV['CANONICAL_HOST'], force_ssl: true if ENV['CANONICAL_HOST']

Comment: I use rack-rewrite, I'm sorry :/

Comment: The issue was with my env variables in local env. Solved it.